# Change handler value when user input in textarea unique data

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

I use bootstrap-slider Kartik extension for Yii2. I want to make slider handler responsive for textarea inputs. For this moment my textarea is responsive for sliding via `slide event`.

before
[image]

after
[image]

How it works right now 
[image]

Comment: i dont quite understand what you are trying to accomplish? what do you mean by make the slider responsive for textarea ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam look at this site https://yammi.io/ There are some sliders, but i can put needed numbers inside textbox directly, after that slider will change handlers position. I want to do the same with my slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understand from your question you are trying to update or refresh the slider if you update the value inside an input.

If that is correct you have to use javascript to bind the `input` event to the input field associated with the slider and then call the `setValue` function of the slider to update it.

A simple javascript example/demo can be seen below where you can change the value inside the input field and the slider will update automatically

```js
// With JQuery
$('#ex1').slider({
  formatter: function(value) {
    return 'Current value: ' + value;
  }
});
$("#range").on("input", function(e) {
  $('#ex1').slider('setValue', $(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.2.0/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.2.0/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>

<input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14" />
<input type="text" id="range" value="" />
```

To implement above in Yii you can use the code below

*Note: change the `#range_input` to the `id` of the input field in your code, and `#slider_input_id` with the `id` of your slider.*

```
$this->registerJs('$("#range_input").on("change",function(){
    $("#slider_input_id").slider("setValue",$(this).val());
})',\yii\web\view::POS_LOAD);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed response.

Comment: I tried to use your suggestion, but it didnt work. Can you please follow this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711920/repost-asking-again-change-event-in-kartiks-bootstrap-slider-extension-for-yi ?