# Repost/ asking again. Change event in Kartik's bootstrap-slider extension for Yii2

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

I asked that question [today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51707925/change-handler-value-when-user-input-in-textarea-unique-data#51709615) and the user gave me best answer, but it seems that its not working. Maybe its all because i use not raw Bootstrap-slider.js but Kartik's extension. So here is what i do:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input  type="text" 
                class="form-control" 
                id="test"
                placeholder="50000">
        <?php echo Slider::widget([
                'name'=> 'test-bi',
            'sliderColor'=> Slider::TYPE_GREY,
            'pluginEvents' => [
                 'slide' => "function(slideEvt) {
                        $('#test').val(slideEvt.value); 
                    }",
            ],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'min'=>50000,
            'max'=>200000,
            'step'=>1,
            'tooltip'=>'hide',
            ],
            ]);
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks like:[image]
As you can see `slide` trigger works nice, but i also trying to update or refresh the slider if the value inside an input is changed. The answer that i got not working for

```
$this->registerJs(
    "$('#test').on('change',function(){
        $('#w17-slider').slider('setValue',$(this).val());
    })",
    \yii\web\view::POS_LOAD);
```

May be its all because i use extension? Is there is the way to use `change` trigger inside `<?php widget ?>` ?

Comment: There is no good reason to repost this question. Especially after only 4 hours, you should have edited/updated your original question instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change handler value when user input in textarea unique data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51707925/change-handler-value-when-user-input-in-textarea-unique-data)

Comment: added an answer see if it helps

Comment: do mark the ans if it worked

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam i will check your suggestion. Thank you very much for your helping, but right now i cant work with my computer cause im on vacation in Cremia. There is one internet at all ))) Soon i will connect through wifi and check this ans. Thank you.

Comment: oops ! never knew that. No problem, enjoy your vacations to the max, take your time.

Comment: the only thing i find odd is the `name` field from the database column being used as the `id` attribute for the elements try changing to the field `id` of you table column as the name could contain spaces and make weird effect when trying to access via javascript otherwise your code still works for me and i dont get any error like you specified , try removing the extension fromt he vendor directory and run `compose update` again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always keep your console or developer bar open when working with javascript, you never know when something conflicts with the other.

You need to use `parseInt()` to pass a value to the `setValue` function of the slider,  it is interpreting it as text, otherwise, it throws

> Uncaught Error: Invalid input value '1' passed in

if you are getting the same error as above in your console when you type in the text box, then you need to change the code to the following

```
$this->registerJs(
    "$('#test').on('input',function(){
        $('#w17-slider').slider('setValue',parseInt($(this).val()));
    })",
    \yii\web\view::POS_READY);
```

Comment: what was this for @BrokenCoin

Comment: omg, it is worst internet. Wait just a second, i will edit my post.

Comment: `$this->registerJs(
    "$('.amount').on('input',function() {
        $('#' + this.id + '-slider').slider('setValue',parseInt($(this).val()));
    })",
    \yii\web\view::POS_READY);`
https://hastebin.com/yocilomipi.bash
Here what i did. I choose to use class `.amount` instead of id, cause i have several sliders and input fields. Nevertheless, i got an error. **cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call 'setValue'**

I am sorry that i cant prettify my post. Internet... Hope this post will be informative for you.

Comment: so you have multiple slider dedicated to multiple inputs? i can update the answer but it would be hard for me to guess until you show your actual structure for the form where you are using, try adding the view code as it is, here in your question by editing it or add a link to pastebin @BrokenCoin

Comment: @BrokenCoin it does work, all three sliders, you have a min and max value too high maybe you are testing with 1,2,3 which does not make difference while sliding try incrementing or changing the value in multiples of 5000, and you will see the slider moving , your code is ok to be used with class.

Comment: Hmm...Maybe something wrong with my setup? Why do i get this error **cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call 'setValue'**? Can i show you my entire view.php file?

Comment: yeah sure go ahead @BrokenCoin

Comment: Look, i add the answer. Now everything work fine. Thank you for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solutions. So i decided to use JUI slider intead of Kartik's slider. Here is my code:

```
<?php echo Slider::widget([
        'clientOptions' => [
            'min' => 1,
            'max' => 200000,
        ],
        'clientEvents' => [
            'slide'=> "function (event, ui) {
              $('#" .$value['strategy_title']   . "-amount').val(ui.value);
        }"
        ],
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'slider',
            'id' => $value['strategy_title']    . '-slider',
        ],
    ]);
?>
```

And js expression from @MuhammadOmerAslam

```
$this->registerJs("$('.amount').on('input',function() { 
         $('.slider').slider('value', $(this).val());
    })", 
    \yii\web\view::POS_READY);
```